# Upload Zipper folder in Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new with asp.net and I developed a Islamic site and now I want to upload a zip folder with Quran-e-Pak(files) inside it on my [read quran online](http://www.onlinequranreading.org/OnlineQuran.aspx) page so when a visitor click on download link that zipped folder download on his/her computer.

I have searched and found many relevant links to upload zip folder using upload control but my requirement is that I don't want to upload folder from site's page but instead I want to upload zip folder myself from aspx page or using c# from back end and visitor could be able to download it by just clicking the link.

Is there any way to use html tag for this or using which way will be best for this?